# Show Tables Query in my App

Tags: java, sql-server

Hello guys I'm making an application that accesses MySQL & MsSQL databases that fiddles about with them and depending which one it accessed prints out the tables, and the part of the code that does that is this:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, userName,password);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;

if (driverCN.startsWith("com.mysql")) {       // For MySQL.
rs = stmt.executeQuery("Show Tables");
    } else {                                  // For MsSQL
rs = stmt.executeQuery("??????");
        }
// Displays the remaining Database tables.
       System.out.println("\nThese are the remaining Database Tables:\n");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String db = rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println(db);
        }
```

Now what I want to know, is how do I make this work for MsSQL as well, what kind of query do I execute and will the results be passed onto my result set? ( this works perfectly for MySQL database, I simply don't have MsSQL database to test this on just yet. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 or 2008:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
```

SQL Server 2000:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='U'
```

Comment: Not really I think ... Your table names will be in the column TABLE_NAME in case of 2005 or 2008 for example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx

Comment: So you need not to do a select * from select only the TABLE_NAME column. If you're in SQL Server 2000, check the columns of the sysobjects table to get the right column.

Comment: And finally don't forget to accept the answer to close this question ;)

Comment: I see. Well the company will be using SQL Server 2008, The main code cleans up Database Cache tables. And this part of the code is will display the remainder tables. Do you have any suggestions that would be liable for both SQL server and MySQL?

Comment: I always accept the answers ^_^ ( simply have to wait for the timer to run out )

Comment: Suggestion about what ? Cleaning the database cache tables or displaying the remainder tables ?

Comment: Displaying the remainder tables, I'm trying to make this code reusable on both databases, it works perfectly fine with MySQL as it prints the remainder tables at the end one by one, would like to make the same with SQL server. At the moment I got:
 
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables");

Comment: And then the while loop shown above in my code, so what Kind of editions would I have to make to the query, so it works with Result set?

Comment: You use SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables insteand of select * and it should do the trick :)

Comment: Thank you sir, this helps me a bunch! :3 I'm not used to SQL server ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
select name from sys.tables where type='u'
```